# Cannot remove or purge mysql-server after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, dpkg, mysql

I tried running mysql after upgrading to 20.04, but it couldnt, so I tried removing it, but everytime i try to use the package, wherever is removing or purging, i always stumble into this:

```
lsudo apt purge  mysql-server
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Il pacchetto "mysql-server" non è installato e quindi non è stato rimosso
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
1 non completamente installati o rimossi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 0 B di spazio su disco.
Configurazione di mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
2021-02-24T17:09:52.048092Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Err
or while setting value 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE
_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2021-02-24T17:09:52.049668Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing
 common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto mysql-server-8.0 script post-installation
 ha restituito lo stato di errore 1
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried including those values to sql-mode in the my.cnf file, but it won't work.

Please, help!

Comment: Seems packages have been corrupted or broken. Try configure dpkg by running following command `sudo dpkg ––configure –a`

Answer (score 1):

To solve the following error:

```
dpkg: Error processing mysql-server-8.0 (--configure) package:
 the thread installed mysql-server-8.0 script post-installation package
 returned error status 1
There were errors in processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Create a `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postrm` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/true
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using synaptic package manager. If you do not have it installed use this guide:

https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/

Then, once you have it installed, you can fix/delete/reinstall the file by searching for the mysql package.